# Is there a windows api function to determine if the hidden window is closed or not using its handle?

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a handle(IntPtr) to a hidden window, which terminates/quits automatically after a certain amount of time, say after a mintue. Is there a function in windows api to determine if the hidden window is has terminated or not using its handle?

Please note that the window is hidden using ShowWindow external function with 0 as the value of parameter **nCmdShow**.

Answer (score 5):

The [IsWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function should do what you asked for. However you should use caution: window handles can be recycled so your window may be closed and its handle assigned to some other new window.

Comment: Incase the handle is recycled and assigned to another window, what is the most reliable way to identify my application?

Comment: Probably something like [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You can check the class, process, of the window, etc. It's still not reliable though and you should really use a notification system.

Comment: @Amazed- I tried to use IsWindow function but it always returns true even if the window has been closed. Again if I use the FindWindowEx it always returns one particular handle if I have more than window with same class and title.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could check with `IsWindow` if it still exists. See [MSDN for further information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the window is being just hidden, using ShowWindow(0) (ie SW_HIDE), then likely the HWND will still be valid, so IsWindow() will return TRUE. To check for a valid HWND being visible vs invisible, use the [IsWindowVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530(v=vs.85).aspx) USER32 call.

Depending on the target application, you might want to use this in addition to IsWindow(), plus checking the pid and class to guard against HWND recycling.